# Exact sequence induced by two head-to-tail arrows

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to C$ be two arrows in an abelian category $\mathsf{A}$. Prove that they induce an exact sequence:

$$0 \to kerf \to kergf \to kerg \to cokerf \to cokergf \to cokerg \to 0$$

This is exercise 8.4.6 in *Category Theory for Working Mathematicians*.

Here is my attempt:

This looks much like a corrolary of the snake lemma. I tried to ensemble them into a [diagram (q.uiver link)](https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsMTIsWzAsMCwia2VyZiJdLFsyLDAsImtlcmdmIl0sWzQsMCwia2VyZyJdLFswLDYsImNva2VyZiJdLFsyLDYsImNva2VyZ2YiXSxbNCw2LCJjb2tlcmciXSxbMCwyLCJhIl0sWzAsNCwiYiJdLFsyLDIsImEiXSxbMiw0LCJjIl0sWzQsMiwiYiJdLFs0LDQsImMiXSxbNiw3LCJmIiwxXSxbMCw2XSxbMSw4XSxbOCw5LCJnZiIsMV0sWzksNF0sWzIsMTBdLFsxMCwxMSwiZyIsMV0sWzExLDVdLFs2LDgsImlkIiwxXSxbOCwxMCwiZiIsMV0sWzcsOSwiZyIsMV0sWzksMTEsImlkIiwxXSxbNywzXSxbMCwxXSxbMSwyXSxbMyw0XSxbNCw1XV0=) but this does not seem to work as the middle rows are far from exact.

In this [diagram (again q.uiver link)](https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsOSxbMiwyLCJhIl0sWzQsMiwiYiJdLFs2LDIsImMiXSxbMCwwLCJrZXJmIl0sWzIsMCwia2VyZ2YiXSxbNCwwLCJrZXJnIl0sWzQsNCwiY29rZXJmIl0sWzYsNCwiY29rZXJnZiJdLFs4LDQsImNva2VyZyJdLFszLDRdLFs0LDVdLFswLDEsImYiLDFdLFsxLDIsImciLDFdLFs1LDFdLFs0LDBdLFsxLDZdLFsyLDddLFs2LDddLFs3LDhdLFsyLDhdLFszLDBdXQ==) the 'connecting' morphism $kerg \to cokerf$ is obvious. However, there seems not to exist an easy method to check exactness other than laboriously chasing elements.

Comment: Hint: Try fiddling with the entries in your diagram such that the middle rows are exact. You are on the right track, wanting to use the snake lemma.

Comment: @JuliusJ. Thats exactly what I have tried but it seemed impossible. To fit $a \to a \to b$ into a short exact sequence without any restrictions whatsoever... I cannot figure out how that would work.

Comment: I found the solution presented as an exercise in *Algebre Commutative* by Bourbaki. I will write an answer shortly-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right with the idea to ensemble all $f,g,gf$ into a snake lemma diagram and here is its [construction (q.uiver link)](https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsMTAsWzEsMCwiQSJdLFsyLDAsIkEgXFxvcGx1cyBCIl0sWzMsMCwiQiJdLFsxLDEsIkIiXSxbMiwxLCJCIFxcb3BsdXMgQyJdLFszLDEsIkMiXSxbMCwwLCIwIl0sWzAsMSwiMCJdLFs0LDAsIjAiXSxbNCwxLCIwIl0sWzIsNSwiLWciXSxbMSw0LCIoaSxnZikgXFxjaXJjIFQiXSxbMCwzLCJmIl0sWzAsMSwiKGksZikiXSxbMyw0LCIoaSxnKSIsMl0sWzEsMiwiaS1mIl0sWzQsNSwiaS1nIiwyXSxbNiwwXSxbMiw4XSxbNSw5XSxbNywzXV0=). This diagram is precisely the mapping cone of this simpler [diagram](https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsOCxbMCwxLCJBIl0sWzAsMiwiQiJdLFsxLDIsIkIiXSxbMSwzLCJDIl0sWzAsMCwiMCJdLFswLDMsIjAiXSxbMSwxLCIwIl0sWzEsNCwiMCJdLFswLDEsImYiLDJdLFsyLDMsImciXSxbNCwwXSxbMSw1XSxbMyw3XSxbNiwyXSxbMSwyLCJpZF9CIl0sWzUsM10sWzAsNl1d), which should be of interest.